# Select employees, who are managers but also working under a manager

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, self-join

I am trying to build a query to select all employees, who are managers but also working under a manger.

For example in below table

| id | name | manager_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | fresher | 2 |
| 2 | team lead | 3 |
| 3 | manager | null |

I want to get only the team lead, as result of my select query, I tried using the below query, but I am getting an error. Also I am not sure whether this is a correct way to do it.

```
select e.id, e.name, m.name as mgr_name, 
case when EXISTS (select 1 from emps where emps.manager_id = e.id) then 1
     else 0 end as isMgr
from emps e 
join emps m on e.mgr_id = m.id
where e.manager_id is not null and e.isMgr = 1
```

Error:

> Invalid column name 'isMgr'.

Comment: @DaleK updated the question.

Comment: You can't reference a calculated column in the where clause unless you include it in a sub-query. Otherwise you have to repeat the logic used in the calculation.

Comment: Ok, is there any other solution than using sub-query?

Comment: What with the avoiding a sub-query? Sub-queries are great!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I would just use `exists` and filtering:

```
select e.*
from emps e
where e.manager_id is not null and
      exists (select 1
              from e e2
              where e2.manager_id = e.id
             );
```

Comment: So except using a nested query, there is no other solution.

Comment: @user1734269 . . . You could use a `join` instead.  This just seems like the simplest solution.